# SonataUserAdminBundle: Link to Admin Action

Tags: routes, symfony, bundle

Hello how can i link to a SonataUserAdmin Controller Page ie. list in a Twig Template?

Are there predefined Routes for each Entities controller?

I cannot find a specific controller because this module is using easy-extends.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can see the apropriate route names in the debug control bar.